# ANDROID DEVICE TYPE

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I try to create Android Emulator in IntelliJ IDEA 15, there are many types of device.I don't know what these device are and where it used for smart-phone, android TV or wear watch. I think that these are for android emulator GUI.
Please explain what device type is to be used while creating AVD and for what.

Comment: Select a device which is suitable according to your requirement. As the app design and development is bit different in each type of device .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an AVD based on an existing device definition:

1. click Create Virtual Device.
2. In the Select Hardware window, select a device configuration, such as Nexus 6, then click Next.
3. Select the desired system version for the AVD and click Next.
       Verify the configuration settings, then click Finish.
4. If necessary, click Show Advanced Settings to select a custom skin for the hardware profile and adjust other hardware settings.

   To launch the AVD in the Android Emulator, click the launch button
   in the list of AVDs.

Answer (score 0):

see this tutorial in this u have a step how to create a AVD.
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html